# Django User Model Methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have Auth and Profile implemented into my system however i'd like to extend the User model and I don't know what is considered the 'correct' way of doing this.

I just want to create a method that returns a link for the user like:

```
<a href="URL" class="GroupName">Username</a>
```

I figured that this is probably best done using a method as the link will change and I don't want to be going through all my template files fixing this.

This may be common to somebody using Django but I have not used it much so I am not well versed in the conventions so any advice would be great

Answer (score 0):

If you're not altering what is stored in the database, the easiest way is a proxy model. Here's an example straight out of the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MyPerson(Person):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```

If you want to do something more complex than adding methods to the User model, such as adding new data fields, I would recommend creating a Model with a one-to-one relation to User.

Comment: Yea I looked at proxy models but i'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: You just create a new Model that extends User, with the Meta class defined as above. Then you can methods to the Model.

Comment: I mean where do I have the file and whats it called etc? I've jsut made a file called userproxy.py in the webroot as I don't know where it should be

Comment: In Django all models go in models.py for your application. Read the documentation, the "polls tutorial" is a good place to start:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: So your saying I need to create a model file in a dir and have it installed in the app? I'm trying this and it's saying "No module named users.UserManager" and there is a classed called UserManager in users/models.py

Comment: I have managed to get somewhere, however it now has an error with the names: "Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'accounts.User'" Is there a simple way around this? Can i just reference it as User?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to create URLs in Django without needing to worry about changing them is to use the `{% url %}` tag. See [the documentation on reversing URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking specifically for extending the user model but have you considered creating a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to generate the link instead?
If you only need the method in the templates than that's definitely the way to go.